# check what 32-bit packages are installed on a 64-bit server

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, rpm

I'd like to check the binaries installed on my server and know if the is a 32-bit binary installed.

`rpm -qa` would give me all the packages installed. However if i try to `grep` through it like so, `rpm -qa | grep x86` it would again list all the packages.

Is there another way to find if 32-bit packages are installed?

- OS - CentOS 6.4
- arch- 64 bit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can query RPM database for architecture of installed packages. This command will list all installed packages and their architecture:

```
rpm -qa --queryformat '%{NAME} %{ARCH}\n'
```

So if you want to find 32-bit packages only you can check the above list for architectures i686, i586, i486 and i386:

```
rpm -qa --queryformat '%{NAME} %{ARCH}\n' | grep 'i[6543]86' | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Answer (score 5):

Would

```
yum list installed *.i*86
```

do what you want ? There's more information on this [here](http://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General#head-357346ff0bf7c14b0849c3bcce39677aaca528e9) in the CentOS General faq.

Comment: Make it `yum list installed *.i*86` and it will.

Answer (score -1):

Just grep for x86_32:

```
rpm -qa | grep -i  "x86_32"
```

Comment: I am sorry, this answer is wrong (as of 2013 and as of 2021), the RPM architecture on Fedora and RHEL (and its derivatives, such as CentOS) for 32 bit Intel architecture packages was always i386, i486, i586 or i686.